# Can I push my GIT repo and LFS files separately?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I use a GitLab server and I have a very big Git repository locally. Is there a way to push my source **first**, and **then** with a second command the LFS objects?

This is my command chain at the moment:

```
cd foo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin <IP>
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```